# Python: Pyqt Receive Hex format integer only from Plaintext

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I want to receive single byte data from user from a **plaintext_edit** but i want to make sure it is entered in hex format, 0x with prefix or else will result in unknown type

Example : 0x3f

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say but I am guessing you are using `pyqt`. Define a handler for the  control's keyPressEvent and filter the user input there. That won't raise a type error. Instead you ensure that only valid data gets entered.